# Syncing Azure Easy Table with WHERE clause

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms app which uses an Azure app service with SQL database linked through EasyTables. I've run the samples and successfully tested querying tables etc on the server and enabled offline sync so as a localdb is created.

I've created the store, defined the table & sync'd it, however I want to be able to query it somehow with a where clause - is that possible? Can I add a where clause to the client.GetSyncTable line?

```
var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("localstore.db");
store.DefineTable<Journey_Stages>();
client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
tbl_Stages = client.GetSyncTable<Journey_Stages>();
```

Some of the tables I'm pulling down will grow over time & are linked to individual user profiles, so I only want data which belongs to that user and I don't want to be bringing down masses of data each time, preferably let the server handle that and only bring down what I need on a user by user basis.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this filtering logic on the server side, so that each user's data isn't exposed to all your other users. See for example [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/blob/master/backend/node/TodoSample/tables/todoitem.js) if you are using the Node.js backend -- line 17 adds a WHERE clause for the table read query. If you have the .Net backend, similar logic would go in your table controller.

```
// Configure specific code when the client does a request
// READ - only return records belonging to the authenticated user
table.read(function (context) {
  context.query.where({ userId: context.user.id });
  return context.execute();
});
```

Comment: Thank you - now worked out where I can put backend code in my App Service to do client side filtering. I presume I then just use the normal async code above, but the server will filter for only data associated with my account?